# javascript inline comment inside function call

Tags: javascript, function, comments, inline

So I am having this document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
                alert("document is ready");
            });

            $(window).on("load", function () {
                //executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
                alert("window is loaded");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the inline comments inside the 2 function calls.

Apparently these do NOT work and give me an error:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after function body[Weitere Informationen] index:1:297 note: { opened at line 1, column 37
```

However using a multiline comment `/* */` is working just perfectly.
I`m assuming, that the single line comments dont work becuase somehow the javascript gets minified into one line. 
Can sombody evaluate an how this is happening?
Where can you use single line comments and where not?
Or is it just generally a bad idea to use single line comments in js?

Comment: Are you minifying it yourself, or are you using an external tool for that?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir im using the phalcon php framework as MVC. If i just load a plain html file this behaviour does not occour. Maybe this is a bug in rendering different views with phalcon using the {{ }} notation. Im not explicitly minifiying anything myself.(but mybe the framework does something like that -.-)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for your replay. it is in fact the phalcon framework minifiying the document:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after minifying everything is just one line, a single line comment, which doesn't have an end-of-comment tag, doesn't work.